# how to keep alive my ID without Hiddenfor in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

i am a new developer for asp.net MVC. i have a edit button on gridview after click edit in popup model i can see every data. For example:

in my Db has customer table 4 columns: id(PK), Name, Surname, contact i can not see id textbox it is normal! but after clicking edit button Changing Name,SurName sending HttpPost Edit controller . there is a surprise event: ıd is disappear! After googling :

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Kortingartikel")) { 

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Artikelid)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Artikelnaam)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prijs)

}
```

Hiddenfor is a solution. But the solution can not satisfy me . why id disappear and how to hold id value without hiddenfor?

Comment: And what is wrong with saving the id in a hidden field? It seems to me to be the best solution here.

Comment: i can not use hidden field i am sending my model with parameter to edit prosess. Why disappear id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not asp.net webform wich uses viewstate to store informations.
The MVC uses pure html without workaround. 
So, basically, what it's not in the post simply does not exists.

A way to not use the HiddenFor, that I can think of, could be to have your Id in the Url.
The Frmaework should be smart enough to bind it to a method like this

```
 public ViewResult MyAction(int id, MyViewModel viewModel)
 {

 }
```